# HTML CSS works in one file but not another

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm new to HTML and CSS and encountering a baffling problem. I created a very simple HTML file and then attempted to add some CSS to it. I could not get an external style sheet to work so I tried entering it internally. I got this to work but only with basic element selectors (it will not work with any id selectors). I was sure I was entering everything correctly though so I copied and pasted [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax_id) into a new html file. The example it worked as it should. So then I opened a new file and typed directly what was in the example into the new file myself word-for-word, and it doesn't work! I've gone over it countless times and there are no typos. What could possibly be causing this?

The code that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#para1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="para1">My Name</p>
<p>Hi and welcome to my website.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The code the doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#para1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id=“para1”>My Name</p>
<p>Hi and welcome to my website.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copy your code in pastebin

Comment: And look to your dev console for error

Comment: the only difference what I see is the double quotation: `"para1"` != `“para1”`

Comment: the quotes in you faulty example are wrong. Make sure to disable "curly quotes" on your mac, or use an editor that does not replace those automatically http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p id=“para1”>My Name</p>
```

should be changed to

```
<p id="para1">My Name</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. What an infuriating autocorrect.